# Are there any good, modern, online guides to hand optimizing assembly code?

Tags: optimization, assembly

I'm working on some code which contains some (compiler generated) chunks of assembly code that we've identified are speed bottle necks.

I know enough about assembly to muddle through and look for manual optimizations - I'm wondering, though, if there are any good, online guides that offer reusable techniques to be used in hand-optimizing assembly. This is not something I expect I'll have to do very often, so odds are I'll have to learn how to do it, again, from scratch, each time.

Comment: If you have a specific architecture in mind, please tag appropriately ("x86" or "arm" or whatever).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf

I'd say "have fun", but it would probably be really mean-spirited :(

I think you're interested in Chapter 9, "Optimizing for Speed".

Comment: That looks like a great book.  I'd also recommend Chapter 13 on vector programming.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.agner.org/optimize/

http://www.intel.com/intelpress/sum_swcb2.htm - have to buy, and stresses intrinsics rather than assembly

Answer (score 1):

While this might not need saying...

In general, you'll go a lot further by helping the compiler (I'm using GCC as an example, but this should be relevant for other compilers too):

- Play with compiler options for a while (-march=native, -mfpmath=sse, -msse3, -marm, -mthumb)
- Use profiling information when you can (-fprofile-generate, -fprofile-use)
- Tweak the algorithm to see what produces "better" code (`(x>>8)&0xFF` or `(x&0xFF00)>>8`? It's one instruction on PPC, but the compiler might use two)
- Tweak your algorithm so it uses the cache better.
- Use [vector extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions) if your compiler supports them. Your compiler may have additional [target-specific builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Target-Builtins.html#Target-Builtins) ([x86](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html), [ARM NEON](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html#ARM-NEON-Intrinsics)).
- Use a better compiler (RVCT for ARM, ICC for x86)

I'd be surprised if you could get more than a 20% speed-up over a decent C compiler, unless there are specific instructions/features which the compiler isn't using. And 20% is rarely worth writing home about unless it's all your app does.

Comment: +1 for a good answer and to cancel out the unwarranted downvote - this is a very important point - it's pretty hard to beat a *good* compiler when it comes to optimisation on modern CPUs

Answer (score 1):

Agner Fog's site seems to be a common response.  Another page that I have found particularly useful over the years has been Paul Hsieh's page at ...

http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/tech.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answers suggesting [Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/)'s optimisation manuals. They are really great.

In addition, however, Intel and AMD also provide some freely available optimisation manuals, e.g. the following may be of interest to you:

[Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www3.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf)

[Software Optimization Guide for AMD Family 10h Processors](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/40546-PUB-Optguide_3-11_5-21-09.pdf)